# Google Analytics Library IOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics

When i add google analytics library, i have this warning

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSSQLiteErrorDomain", referenced from:
      l003 in libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIDataStore.o)
```

Please help me

Comment: One these are not warnings, these are errors. Two, how is this related to Xcode? It's not Xcode that complains but its underlying compiler...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add `libGoogleAnalytics.a` to your target setting `[Build phases]-[Link Binary with Libraries]`.  Also check if  `libsqlite3.0dylib` (where GA stores tracking data) and `CFNetwork.framework` are added there as they are required for `Google Analytics/iOS (version 2.0 beta 3)`.

P.S. For Google `Analytics/iOS version 3.0` `CoreData framework` is required instead.

Comment: @sagimann You are right, since Analytics 3.0 CoreData framework is required.

Comment: I ended up adding CoreData.framework, libz.dylib and libGoogleAnalytics.a and only after that it worked.

Comment: Why doesn't their [Getting Started article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3) mention the need of `libGoogleAnalytics.a`?!

Answer (score 13):

I had have the same issue on `NSAttributeDescription`. In documentation this function is from `CoreData.framework`, so I have added this framework and no more errors on that issue.

Answer (score 9):

Problem related to **Google Analytics SDK for iOS v2 migration**.

*I am not sure which topic to write it to as there is no exact problem--I've bumped into and solved by my own--found (this one seems to be the closest (not sure if I should open a new one)), but might be helpfull for someone.*

**Problem:**

I have my previous (1.5.1) SDK installed in **"SDKs/GoogleAnalytics SDK"** separate folder. On v2 migration I've placed the new files into **"SDKs/GoogleAnalytics SDK v2"**. After following all the instructions about migration (from Google site) (and, in details, that was just removing the previous references to the files from the first folder and adding the new ones from the new one), I started to get the following error message on compilation:

> Undefined symbols for architecture **armv7**:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

I went trough first pages of googling (and stackoverflowing) and the most popular solution suggested was "to set '**Build active architecture only**' property to '**YES**'" (my active architectures are "armv7 armv7s"). **But** that **DID NOT HELP** at all.

**Solution:**

However, a miracle happened. I've noticed that there is an **old directory** "SDKs/GoogleAnalytics SDK" was listed in linker pathes. So, **after that directory removing** (as I don't know where the list of the directories exists in settings) everything started to compile and work like a charm (also setting 'Build active architecture only' to 'YES' was not necessary for me).

Comment: Maybe it was listed in "Build Settings > Library Search Paths"

Comment: Might be so - it was hard to locate the core of the problem. But the thing was that I've done everything as migration guide says, where saw no references to the option you are mentioning.

Answer (score 7):

Add -lGoogleAnalyticsServices in Build settings -> Other Linker Flags

Comment: This is exactly what my issue was. Need to Add Framework / Add Other... / select file "libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a" and done, error went away. This file is not mentioned in the "Getting Started" documentation.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar errors as above, actually more (SDK 2.0 beta 4).  After adding the Analytics library/headers, linking with these two frameworks solved the issues:

`CoreData.framework` and `SystemConfiguration.framework`

Answer (score 4):

I followed [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios) tutorial. It says to add

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
```

into the `NameofTheProject-Prefix.pch` file.

And additionally to `CoreData.framework` and `SystemConfiguration.framework` add `libz.dylib`
It solved all issues.

Comment: Adding libz.dylib solves the problem for me. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue because i didn't add the **libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a** file. The problem just got resolved as i added this file and built the project again.

Answer (score 0):

I had an ODD odd issue. For some reason `libGoogleAnalytics.a` was in **Copy Bundle Resources** when it was *supposed* to be in **Link Binary With Libraries**

Hopefully that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue after migrating to SDK 2.0 beta 4. Resolved by removing old GA library path from **My Build Settings > Library Search Paths** as pointed by Adri.

Answer (score 0):

I followed all suggestions and I was still getting an error on `XCODE 5.1.1`.

For me the error was in target > Build Setting > Architecture > Architectures.

I replaced the value with `ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT` and the error was gone.

Maybe the `libGoogleAnalytics` lib was not compiled for 64 BIT architecture.

Hope this will help someone. Or get latest lib which is compiled for 64 Bit.

Answer (score 0):

If using **Cocoapods** make sure **Other linker flags** has only `$(inherited)` flag and remove any child **architecture** flags.

For **framework search paths** and **Library search paths** also set only `$(inherited)` flag.

Inside the header bridging file put the `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`