# AdMob issues and errors

Tags: ios, admob, linker-errors, ads

I am trying to implement AdMob to my iOS app. I followed the documentation that they provide [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals). So I try to build and run and I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_NSOverwriteMergePolicy", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
  "_NSSQLiteErrorDomain", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSSQLiteStoreType", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataProvider.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStoreCoordinator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**EDIT 1:** I added the Storekit and MessageUI frameworks as well as added the `Obj-C` linker flag and now I'm getting this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_NSOverwriteMergePolicy", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      -[GAIDataStore contextWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      -[GAIDataStore contextWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      -[GAIDataStore contextWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSSQLiteErrorDomain", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      -[GAIDataStore performBlockAndWait:withError:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      -[GAIDataStore performBlockAndWait:withError:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_NSSQLiteStoreType", referenced from:
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      -[GAIDataStore coordinatorWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      -[GAIDataStore coordinatorWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      anon in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      -[GAIDataStore coordinatorWithModel:URL:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGDataProvider.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIHit.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TAGHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIProperty in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIProperty.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIProperty in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIProperty.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIHit in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIHit.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAICoreDataUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStoreCoordinator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGModel.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAIHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIHit.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TAGHit in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGHit.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAIProperty in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAIProperty.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAIProperty in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIProperty.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAIHit in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIHit.o)
  "_llvm_gcda_emit_arcs", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDefaultLogger.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIError.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIHitUtil.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIURLConnection.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAITrackedViewController.o)
      ...
  "_llvm_gcda_emit_function", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDefaultLogger.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIError.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIHitUtil.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIURLConnection.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAITrackedViewController.o)
      ...
  "_llvm_gcda_end_file", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDefaultLogger.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIError.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIProperty.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIHitUtil.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIURLConnection.o)
      ...
  "_llvm_gcda_increment_indirect_counter", referenced from:
      -[GAITrackerImpl gai_set:value:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
      -[GAITrackerImpl gai_get:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
      -[GAITrackerImpl gai_send:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
      -[GAIDataStore performBlockAndWait:withError:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      _GAIReachabilityStatusString in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIReachabilityChecker.o)
      -[GAI defaultTracker] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
      -[GAI setDefaultTracker:] in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
      ...
  "_llvm_gcda_start_file", referenced from:
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDefaultLogger.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDataStore.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIError.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIProperty.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIHitUtil.o)
      ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIURLConnection.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6):

The [AdMob docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) say:

> The SDK library references six iOS development frameworks which may
>   not already be part of your project:
>
> - StoreKit
> - AudioToolbox
> - MessageUI
> - SystemConfiguration
> - CoreGraphics
> - AdSupport
> - EventKit
> - EventKitUI

You can add these frameworks via the project view as shown and explained in the referenced docs. Also you must use -ObjC link flags.

**Edit:**

Be sure to add the Google libs to your project in the same manner that you added the iOS frameworks. Check out [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13119578/1224741).

Comment: Also EventKit and EventKitUI for AdMob 6.12.0

Answer (score 1):

Did you complete step three :

## Add required linker flags

You now need to add -ObjC to the Other Linker Flags of your application target's build setting:

In Xcode's project navigator, press the blue top-level project icon.
Click on your target, then the Build Settings tab.
Under Other Linker Flags, add -ObjC to both Debug and Release.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation